# Provide image parameter with $_GET

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write an html site that shows an image. The image source is defined by:

```
<img src="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']; ?>.jpg">
```

It doesn't do anything besides generating an `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`as it fails to load the ressource, while replacing the source with "1.jpg" renders the image. The href links to `example.com/page.html?id=1`.

Do I have to include something like `<?php $id = $_GET['id']; ?>` at the beginning of the body?

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Slideshow Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./img/Shortcut.ico" type="image/ico">

  </head>
  <body class="a12">
  <?php /**$id = $_GET['id']; **/?>
    <div align="center">
                  <tr height="460">
                    <td class="a10" height="460" width="566">
                      <div align="center"></div>
                      <img src="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']); ?>.jpg" alt="an image" height="460" border="0">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well… what's the HTML being generated here, the actual URL that the browser is trying to fetch? Since there's a syntax error in your PHP I'd bet it's not "1.jpg"…

Comment: Your code has a typo, you never closed the function call to `htmlspecialchars()`.  Also, show what the actual resulting HTML is.

Comment: The browser is trying to fetch `<?%20echo%20htmlspecialchars($_GET[%27id%27]);%20?>.jpg`, why is the php code not resolved ?

Comment: Does *any* PHP code on that page work…?

Answer (score 0):

please include php in your code.

replace

```
<img src="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']; ?>.jpg">
```

with

```
<img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']); ?>.jpg">
```

Comment: I fixed that typo. Does my html code need to include a .php file? I thought that it would also work by just including the neccessary php code with `<?php ?>` Tags.

Comment: if u want to call a  php file externally then u can include it.in this case no need to do this.